# PHP Libsodium default encryption method

Tags: php, encryption, methods, default, libsodium

I'm sure this must've been asked and answered but can't find where...

With libsodium in PHP (7.0 / 7.1), what is the default encryption method employed (or where to find it) when you do something like this?

```
$enc = sodium_crypto_secretbox($data, $mykey, $sodiumkey);
```

A client wants it stated in the handover documentation but I can't find what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm details

- Encryption: XSalsa20 stream cipher
- Authentication: Poly1305 MAC

Taken from https://doc.libsodium.org/secret-key_cryptography/secretbox

Answer (score 1):

`crypto_secretbox`, `crypto_box` and `crypto_seal` use the XSalsa20 stream cipher for encryption. `crypto_secretstream` uses the XChaCha20 stream cipher.

All of these use Poly1305 for the authentication tag.